# What is the best starting book for someone aiming to learn the basics of programming (101)?

Tags: apache, html-parsing, computer-science

I am just looking for a leaping off point to begin my self-studies in programming.  The SEO and front-end design world has peeked my interest into back-end studies.

I would much appreciate help finding a starting point for my leisure studies / a piece of literature that is commonly considered the best 101 for the computer programming world, if such a book exists.  I presume it does...?

Thank you kindly for any input or recommendation.

- Austin

Comment: Don't ask for opinions.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score -3):

I think video course is more engaging and understandable than the book for starting. and there are so many programming courses online that you can find both free and paid courses on:

1. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/)
2. [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/)
3. [Linda](https://www.lynda.com/)
4. [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/)
5. [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/)

and for the front-end web development books, you can't definitely go wrong with these 2 books :

1. [HTML and CSS: Design and Build Websites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118008189)
2. [JavaScript and JQuery: Interactive Front-End Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118531647)

and from here you can choose your own specific interested web development language/platform: PHP, Ruby, Python, NodeJS, etc.